# mega length usb cables

Tags: usb, home-networking, wireless-router

I have a Actiontec GT-701WR DSL router with 1.5 mbps internet, connected to my main pc via ethernet. I have a D-Link usb wireless adapter on my other PC which won't pick-up the router signal (although every other device picks up signal anywhere in the house i.e. laptop, PS3, etc). I'm on a budget and can't afford a different adapter. I am thinking of connecting using the usb output on router, but this means a cable around 30-feet in length. Any ideas, suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The USB specification defines the maximum cable length of 3 metres (about 10 feet). You can chain repeaters (which cost money) up to about 30 metres (100 feet), but bandwidth will suffer.

I have heard people claim they can get better range using cat5 cable for USB. The electrical characteristics of USB make this unlikely, check the USB [FAQ](http://www.usb.org/developers/usbfaq#cab1).

If you already have a router, just pull the Ethernet cable to the other machine, this will easily reach 30 feet.

Comment: 5 meters, not 3 meters.

Answer (score 0):

I know at least 15ft cables exist without repeaters, but be careful about which ones you pick.

I freelance as a photographer covering various sports tournaments, and using these 15' cables allow three shooters to upload photos simultaneously to a central location from three shooting positions.  This really helps get complete coverage when covering cheering.